# How can I encrypt all data in /var/www so no one except root can access it?

Tags: encryption, virtualization, root

I have a situation that I sell my product on an virtual machine with Ubuntu installed on it and it has a LAMP on it and I do not want any one to be able to copy or access my code.

Of course I have a very secure password for the root, but this is not an issue. Bad guys mound a CD with a live Linux and boot up on my VM so they work around all the passwords and gain access to my code. That is the reason I would like to have all my files and data in the `www` folder to be encrypted.

Comment: You may encrypt any directory see the following answers. [Encrypting Files and folder through terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/98443/encrypting-files-and-folder-through-terminal) and [Is there a tool to encrypt a file or directory?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27770/is-there-a-tool-to-encrypt-a-file-or-directory) But encrypting `www`? how about web access? you don't want that?

Answer (score -1):

If you means owner, I think you can try the `chown` command, also `chmod`. I think it will help you.

Comment: Changing the owner and encryption are not the same thing.  OP is asking about encryption.